# Springboot + Thymeleaf: Failure by parsing a template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i want to show a requested object in HTML and i get a Error and i have no idea what cause my error. Google could not help and now i try to ask you. I don't think the Error comes from my Table, because i commented it out and the error still occour. The Error also not come from "http://localhost:8081/simulation" because i reseive a valid JSON with valid values. Thanks for helping :).

Here is my Code:

ApiController.java:

```
package de.WI18C.Gruppe5.API.controller;
import de.WI18C.Gruppe5.API.model.Unternehmen;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Controller
public class APIContoller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/unternehmen", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewUnternehmen(Model model) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Unternehmen unternehmen = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/simulation", Unternehmen.class);
    model.addAttribute("unternehmen", unternehmen);

    return "unternehmen";
   }
}
```

unternehmen.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="de">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Unternehmen</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-12 align-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 mx-auto">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Attribut</th>
                    <th scope="col">Wert</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getName()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Bestand</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBestand()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Bedarf</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBedarf()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <td>Verkaufspreis</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getVerkaufspreis()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">5</th>
                    <td>Gewinn</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getGewinn()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">6</th>
                    <td>Bestand - Rad</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBestand_rad()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">7</th>
                    <td>Bestand - Rahmen</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBestand_rahmen()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">8</th>
                    <td>Bestand - Lenker</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBestand_lenker()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">9</th>
                    <td>Bestand - Licht</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBestand_licht()}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">10</th>
                    <td>Bestand - Schaltung</td>
                    <td th:text="${unternehmen.getBestand_schaltung()}"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Error i get by call "http://localhost:8080/unternehmen" (sorry for bad formating):

2020-12-16 15:07:55.635 ERROR 3696 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "unternehmen": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/unternehmen.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/unternehmen.html]")
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1394) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1078) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Name cannot be null or empty
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null or empty
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeNames.forHTMLName(AttributeNames.java:478) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions$AttributeDefinitionRepository.storeAttribute(AttributeDefinitions.java:788) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions$AttributeDefinitionRepository.getAttribute(AttributeDefinitions.java:677) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions.forHTMLName(AttributeDefinitions.java:405) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions.forName(AttributeDefinitions.java:336) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleAttribute(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:492) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:360) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleAttribute(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleAttribute(HtmlElement.java:250) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleAttribute(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:529) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:593) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.ParsingAttributeSequenceUtil.parseAttributeSequence(ParsingAttributeSequenceUtil.java:220) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:153) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
... 50 common frames omitted

2020-12-16 15:07:55.638 ERROR 3696 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/unternehmen.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null or empty
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeNames.forHTMLName(AttributeNames.java:478) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions$AttributeDefinitionRepository.storeAttribute(AttributeDefinitions.java:788) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions$AttributeDefinitionRepository.getAttribute(AttributeDefinitions.java:677) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions.forHTMLName(AttributeDefinitions.java:405) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.AttributeDefinitions.forName(AttributeDefinitions.java:336) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleAttribute(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:492) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:360) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleAttribute(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleAttribute(HtmlElement.java:250) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleAttribute(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:529) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleAttribute(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:593) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.ParsingAttributeSequenceUtil.parseAttributeSequence(ParsingAttributeSequenceUtil.java:220) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:153) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1394) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1078) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

Comment: where is your html file located ? it it inside resources/templates ?

Comment: yes, it is stored under resources/templates/unternehmen.html

Comment: i am not sure if it helps or not but you have used same name for controller, html,attributes.

Comment: Good point, i havn't seen that till now. But no this isn't the error... i changed unternehmen.html to unternehmenView.html and i get the same error.... Just with the other name :D.

2020-12-16 16:47:03.257 ERROR 352 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "unternehmenView": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/unternehmenView.html]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your template. I could not replicate it locally but that error means some template tag is not correct when it is parsed.
Thymeleaf errors sadly are not that well communicated.

You could try two things:

A) Debugging

- Put a breakpoint at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler:492
- Execute your view and make sure your application stops in line 492
- You should iterate until variable `attributeName` (at line 490) has a null value (Which I understand is your issue)
- At this point you can inspect parameters nameLine and nameCol and you should be able to tell which line and at what character you have a problem

B) If debugging is too much you could just rebuild a new template from scratch testing it step by step (I think you have to restart your application everytime you make achange to your template file)

Good luck!

Comment: hmm i think i choose Plan B. :D i tried to debugging but i don't understand what are all this variables... If this work i will let you know it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the use of getter inside `thymeleaf` and use just like

```
<td th:text="${unternehmen.name}"></td>
<td th:text="${unternehmen.bestand}"></td>
```

Do it for all properties and it should work.

Comment: i have done what you said, but i still get the same error. i also commented the whole table and i get this Error.

Answer (score 0):

Now i build my html completely new and it works. It is really the same document but there is a different use of the "meta" tag in the new one.

old:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Unternehmen</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- My Table -->
</body>
</html>
```

new:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Unternehmen</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- My Table -->
</body>
</html>
```

.... Thats all. I have the same Java Controller and all the other stuff.
Thanks to want2learn and LucasJC for time and advice.